# How to authenticate Firebase Google API AppCheckToken

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-app-check

I am trying to verify firebase appcheck token through a .NET API, calling Firease Appcheck Google API. To do so, I'm using the endpoint `https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/{projectId}:verifyAppCheckToken` and in the body I pass appCheckToken: "{token}".

The answer I get is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

So, how do I authenticate using the API? I have already set up OAuth 2.0 Client ID in my google cloud console, but I don't really know how to use it.